# Possible to do operations within Handlebars expressions?

Tags: handlebars.js

Say that I want to add a dollar sign to a Handlebars output:

`${{price}}`

When price actually evaluates into a number, the final output looks good: `$100`

But when price hasn't been defined yet, the output is just a lonely dollar sign `$` which looks odd just sitting by itself on the page.

I can define the Handlebars helper to include the dollar sign:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('priceWithDollarSign', function() {
  return( "$" + totalPrice );
});
```

But then I need to define a second helper to display it without a dollar sign:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('priceWithoutDollarSign', function() {
  return totalPrice;
});
```

Would it be possible to just do it inside the Handlebars expression itself?

`{{"$" + price}}` for when I want the dollar sign.

`{{price}}` for when I don't want the dollar sign.

In this way, when `price` hasn't been defined the output is just blank and doesn't look odd on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it for *this* dollar sign case. I guess I can extrapolate this out to other similar situations.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("formatToCurrency", function(number, plain) {
  if (number && plain) {
    return number; //return the plain number
  } else if (number && plain == null ) {
    return ("$" + number); //return the number with $ sign
  } else {
    return null; //return nothing
  }
});
```

If I do

```
{{formatToCurrency price null}}
```

I get `100`

If I do

```
{{formatToCurrency price}}
```

I get `$100`

If `price` is undefined, it is just blank.